# How do I make a button that closes one tkinter window and opens another?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I make a button that closes the current window and opens another, the current window doesn't close.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def new_window():
    root.quit()
    new_window = Tk()
    new_window.mainloop()

Button(root, text="Create new window", command=new_window).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

(This isn't my program, it's just an example)

Comment: Multiple main loops are never the answer. Look at the `TopLevel` widget type. Perhaps you can have two of those, one of which is closed and the second is opened.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def new_window():
    root = tk.Tk()
    test = tk.Button(root, text="Create new window", command= lambda:[root.destroy(), new_window()]).pack()

    root.mainloop()

test = tk.Button(root, text="Create new window", command= lambda:[root.destroy(), new_window()]).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This will literally keep opening the exact same window with a button. The lambda allows you to call multiple functions. By calling .destroy() on your root window, it destroys your window, but doesn’t stop the program. Then you create a new root window with your function.

You can use this technique on your actual script.